# Concurrency not running any faster

Tags: go, concurrency

I have written a code, tried to use concurrency but it's not helping to run any faster. How can I improve that?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func checkerr(e error) {

    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }
}

func readFile() {

    file, err := os.Open("data.txt")
    checkerr(err)
    fres, err := os.Create("resdef.txt")
    checkerr(err)

    defer file.Close()
    defer fres.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            words := strings.Fields(scanner.Text())
            shellsort(words)
            writeToFile(fres, words)
            wg.Done()
        }()
        wg.Wait()
    }
}

func shellsort(words []string) {

    for inc := len(words) / 2; inc > 0; inc = (inc + 1) * 5 / 11 {
        for i := inc; i < len(words); i++ {
            j, temp := i, words[i]
            for ; j >= inc && strings.ToLower(words[j-inc]) > strings.ToLower(temp); j -= inc {
                words[j] = words[j-inc]
            }
            words[j] = temp
        }
    }
}

func writeToFile(f *os.File, words []string) {

    datawriter := bufio.NewWriter(f)
    for _, s := range words {
        datawriter.WriteString(s + " ")
    }
    datawriter.WriteString("\n")
    datawriter.Flush()
}

func main() {
    readFile()
}
```

Everything works well except that it take the same time to do everything as without concurrency.

Comment: `wg.Wait` after each goroutine blocks until the goroutine is finished, hence there's effectively no concurrency in your implementation.

Comment: Not only that, but trying to parallelize reading a file is almost never a performance gain. Disks (even SSDs) are many orders of magnitude slower than your RAM and CPU, so unless you're doing some really heavy processing (and you're not here), there's no gain to be had.

Answer (score 3):

You must place `wg.Wait()` after the `for` loop:

```
    for condition {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            // a concurrent job here
            wg.Done()
        }()       
    }
    wg.Wait()
```

Note: the work itself should have a **concurrent** nature.

Here is my tested solution - read from the input file **sequentially** then do `n` **concurrent** tasks and finally  write to the output file **sequentially** in **order**, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/2Fqv_Mrv6cS):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "sort"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

type sortQueue struct {
    index int
    data  []string
}

func main() {
    n := runtime.NumCPU()
    a := make(chan sortQueue, n)
    b := make(chan sortQueue, n)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go parSort(a, b, &wg)
    }
    go func() {
        file, err := os.Open("data.txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer file.Close()
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
        i := 0
        for scanner.Scan() {
            a <- sortQueue{index: i, data: strings.Fields(scanner.Text())}
            i++
        }
        close(a)
        err = scanner.Err()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    fres, err := os.Create("resdef.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer fres.Close()
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(b)
    }()
    writeToFile(fres, b, n)
}

func writeToFile(f *os.File, b chan sortQueue, n int) {
    m := make(map[int][]string, n)
    order := 0
    for v := range b {
        m[v.index] = v.data
        var slice []string
        exist := true
        for exist {
            slice, exist = m[order]
            if exist {
                delete(m, order)
                order++
                s := strings.Join(slice, " ")
                fmt.Println(s)
                _, err := f.WriteString(s + "\n")
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func parSort(a, b chan sortQueue, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for q := range a {
        sort.Slice(q.data, func(i, j int) bool { return q.data[i] < q.data[j] })
        b <- q
    }
}
```

`data.txt` file:

```
1 2 0 3

a 1 b d 0 c 

aa cc bb
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3

0 1 a b c d

aa bb cc
```

Comment: If i place wg.Wait() after the for loop, I receive an error: "unexpected fault address 0x1dbc" and "fatal error: fault"

Comment: Show me compilable code so I could help more.

Comment: Edit your [MCVE] into the question please, don't share pastebin or other links to 3rd party code-hosting platforms.

Comment: See the tested example.

Answer (score 2):

You're not parallelizing anything, because for every call to `wg.Add(1)` you have  matching call to `wg.Wait()`. It's one-to-one: You spawn a Go routine, and then immediately block the main Go routine waiting for the newly spawned routine to finish.

The point of a `WaitGroup` is to wait for *many* things to finish, with a *single* call to `wg.Wait()` when all the Go routines have been spawned.

However, in addition to fixing your call to `wg.Wait`, you need to control concurrent access to your scanner. One approach to this might be to use a channel for your scanner to emit lines of text to waiting Go routines:

```
    lines := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        for line := range lines {
            go func(line string) {
                words := strings.Fields(line)
                shellsort(words)
                writeToFile(fres, words)
            }(line)
        }
    }()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines <- scanner.Text()
    }
    close(lines)
```

Note that this may lead to garbled output in your file, as you have many concurrent Go routines all writing their results at the same time. You can control output through a second channel:

```
    lines := make(chan string)
    out := make(chan []string)

    go func() {
        for line := range lines {
            go func(line string) {
                words := strings.Fields(line)
                shellsort(words)
                out <- words
            }(line)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for words := range out {
            writeToFile(fres, words)
        }
    }()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines <- scanner.Text()
    }
    close(lines)
    close(out)
```

At this point, you can refactor into a "reader", a "processor" and a "writer", which form a pipeline that communicates via channels.

The reader and writer use a single go routine to prevent concurrent access to a resource, while the processor spawns many go routines (currently unbounded) to "fan out" the work across many processors:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    lines := reader()
    out := processor(lines)
    writer(out)
}


func reader() chan<- string {
    lines := make(chan string)

    file, err := os.Open("data.txt")
    checkerr(err)
    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            lines <- scanner.Text()
        }
        close(lines)
    }()

    return lines
}


func processor(lines chan<- string) chan []string {
    out := make(chan []string)

    go func() {
        for line := range lines {
            go func(line string) {
                words := strings.Fields(line)
                shellsort(words)
                out <- words
            }(line)
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func writer(out chan<- []string) {
    fres, err := os.Create("resdef.txt")
    checkerr(err)
    for words := range out {
        writeToFile(fres, words)
    }
}
```

Comment: This only has one worker, so it still effectively has zero concurrency (the only thing that can happen concurrently is the time it takes to erad one line, which is negligible).

Comment: @Adrian That is not correct. I `range` over the `lines` channel and spawn a new Go routine for each message that comes across the channel

Comment: Files `data.txt` and `resdef.txt` are never closed. I would also question whether such a fan-out pattern is sound in a context where the number of lines read by the scanner is unbounded; a concurrency pattern like a pool of workers or semaphore would be safer.

Comment: @jub0bs I agree entirely

Comment: The `processor` and `writer` need to accept read-only (`<-chan`) channels rather than write-only (`chan<-`).

The `processor` may close the `out` channel before goroutines have processed all the lines resulting in `send on closed channel`. A `WaitGroup` can be utilized.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have said, by waiting on the `WaitGroup` each loop iteration, you're limiting your concurrency to 1 (no concurrency). There are a number of ways to solve this, but what's correct depends entirely on *what is taking time*, and that hasn't been shown in the question. Concurrency doesn't magically make things faster; it just lets things happen at the same time, which only makes things faster if things that take a lot of time can happen concurrently.

Presumably, in your code, the thing that takes a long time is the sort. If that is the case, you could do something like this:

```
results := make(chan []string)
for scanner.Scan() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(line string) {
        words := strings.Fields(line)
        shellsort(words)
        result <- words
    }(scanner.Text())
}

go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(results)
}()

for words := range results {
    writeToFile(fres, words)
}
```

This moves the `Wait` to where it should be, and avoids concurrent use of the scanner and writer. This should be faster than serial processing, if the sort is taking a significant amount of processing time.

Comment: I like this approach, my solution is very overwrought by comparison.

Comment: I have tried both both of the solutions and I like that one more. However, after trying to add that to my code I get an error : "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!" What could be wrong?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your code. You could open a new question with the updated code and new error if you're unable to figure out a solution.